# PHP Get days difference between a date and the date today (Now)

Tags: php, date-difference

I can't seem to get this to work. I have tried from the samples online but there wasn't one the is exactly what I needed. Basically I want to be able to display the number of days that passed from the given date. My sample below is a combined HTML and PHP, I had to do it this way for some reasons.

```
<?php
$OldDate = strtotime($row['DateSigned']);
$NewDate = date('M j, Y', $OldDate);
?>

<b>Date Signed:</b> <?php echo $NewDate; ?>
<b>Days Since Signed:</b> <?php echo date_diff(strtotime($NewDate),Date("y/m/d")); ?>
```

This seem to fail.`Date("y/m/d")` is the date today. Can you tell me what went wrong?

Comment: in which format do you want the output. like eg. +5 days?

Comment: Not trying to add days to it though, just trying to get the difference in days. Like 7/10 and 7/20 would be 10 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone, I found a simpler solution (Simpler for beginner like me to understand) :)

```
$now = time(); // or your date as well
$your_date = strtotime($NewDate);
$datediff = ceil(($now - $your_date)/86400);
```

`$datediff` is now showing the number of days.

Comment: $datediff is not showing the difference in days but in seconds. I have divided the answer by 86400 (number of seconds in a day 24*60*60) and used ceil to get the difference in days. ceil($datediff/86400)

Comment: This answer does not give days difference as it also compares with the current time - so the answer will be different today at 00:01 or 23:59. This is not the same as how many calendar days difference (like how many diary pages to turn over). Also it assumes all days are 24 hours long, however with DST this is not the case.

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

```
<?php
$OldDate = strtotime("2015-10-21");
$NewDate = date('M j, Y', $OldDate);
$diff = date_diff(date_create($NewDate),date_create(date("M j, Y")));
?>

<b>Date Signed:</b> <?php echo $NewDate; ?>
<b>Days Since Signed:</b> <?php echo $diff->format('%R%a days'); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Akhil, this also works but I'm trying to get Jesse's solution too as it seem to be in lesser line of codes or simpler. You both got it right though :)

Answer (score 2):

using date_diff, it expects a DateTime object rather than an integer. Here is an example to get you where you may want to be

```
<?php
    $OldDate = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
    $now = new DateTime(Date('Y-m-d'));
    print_r($OldDate->diff($now));
?>
```

This outputs (as of the day of this post) ::

```
[y] => 6
[m] => 0
[d] => 14
[h] => 0
[i] => 0
[s] => 0
[weekday] => 0
[weekday_behavior] => 0
[first_last_day_of] => 0
[invert] => 0
[days] => 2205
[special_type] => 0
[special_amount] => 0
[have_weekday_relative] => 0
[have_special_relative] => 0
```

See [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: How do I get it to show only the days result? I think this worked and is the simplest solution but it is printing out everything, I just need the days. :)

Comment: It's printing an array, just get the value you need

Answer (score 2):

It's too late to reply and there are other good answer but I would like to share what worked for me.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Karachi");
$old_date = new DateTime('2018-12-01 04:10:58');
$now = new DateTime(Date('Y-m-d'));
$interval = $old_date->diff($now);

echo $interval->d.' days<br>';

// you can also get years, month, hours, minutes, and seconds
echo $interval->y.' years<br>';
echo $interval->m.' months<br>';
echo $interval->h.' hours<br>';
echo $interval->i.' minutes<br>';
echo $interval->s.' seconds<br>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is code that will get you the date difference with current date, i hope it helps.

```
    $date = $row['DateSigned'];
    $diff = date_diff(date_create($date), date_create(date('Y-m-d')));
    echo $diff->format("%a");
```

The result you will get is number of days.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use timestamps.

```
$from = mktime(0,0,0,6,1,2015); // example old date
$to = time(); // now

echo round(($to - $from)/86400); // gives you elapsed days
```

86400 is the # of seconds in a day.

Comment: This failed for me, I keep getting 16784 as a result. Can you send me an example solution using my variables and codes above? I can't use `mktime` as the from date is a date taken from mysql date field

Comment: You are converting date to timestamp, then to date in different format, and then trying to convert than to timestamp again. No wonder it's not working for you, you don't seem to know what you're doing...

Comment: @MightyPork - That is why he is here. If he knew exactly what he was doing, he would not be asking the question. This comment is not really needed maybe, right?

Comment: Your answer, in no way addresses the OPs question regarding date_diff. Stating "Screw you guys" and serial downvoting the entire page is not the best way to handle these situations. Maybe you should take a break from your computer for a few minutes. Cheers.

Comment: In fairness, I tried your solution once more and found a way to understand it better.